# Product image disappears on product page when using a custom page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, product-images, page-layouts

I'm creating a custom theme on Magento 2.1. I create a custom layout for the product page in `app/design/frontend/<theme_name>/base/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="layout-1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

  <body> 
  </body>

</page>
```

where `layout-1` is placed in `app/design/frontend/<theme_name>/base/Magento_Theme/page_layout/layout-1.xml` and is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">

  <update handle="1column"/>

</layout>
```

The problem is that when I navigate to a product page the product image/gallery is not displayed.

If I set `catalog_product_view.xml` with `layout="1column"` all works right.

I don't get where is the problem, please help!

---

Below some screenshots:

**With layout `1column` ==> Product image is showed**
[image: Product image]

**With layout `layout-1` ==> Product image is missing**
[image: Image missing]

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. For this, what I did. I assigned the width of the class product media because in magento they assigned the width to the page layout class.